# How to use SqlBulkCopy to write an IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, iasyncenumerable

I have the following method that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<T> RunReport()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = settings };

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/controler");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var linesJson = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                var line = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(linesJson, jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);

                foreach (var line in lines)
                    yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to take that result stream it to the database, using `SqlBulkCopy`'s `WriteToServerAsync` method, but cannot figure out how to turn it into an `IDataReader` or any other type in the `WriteToServerAsync`'s overload list.

I'm open to using something other than bulk copy, provided it's reasonably performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095790/Using-SqlBulkCopy-with-IDataReader-for-Hi-Perf-Ins), I've come up with an IDataReader that takes a IAsyncEnumerable, and implements the appropriate portion of the interface.

```
public class GenericDataReader<T> : IDataReader where T : class
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerator<T> _asychEnumerator;
    private readonly List<FieldInfo> _fields = new List<FieldInfo>();

    public GenericDataReader(IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable)
    {
        _asychEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();

        foreach (FieldInfo fieldinfo in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            _fields.Add(fieldinfo);
        }
    }

    public int FieldCount => _fields.Count;

    public void Dispose() { Close(); }

    public bool Read()
    {
        return _asycEnumerator.MoveNextAsync().Result;
    }

    public async void Close(){ await _asychEnumerator.DisposeAsync(); }

    public Type GetFieldType(int i){ return _fields[i].FieldType; }

    public string GetName(int i) { return _fields[i].Name; }

    public object GetValue(int i){ return _fields[i].GetValue(_asychEnumerator.Current); }
}
```

I'm still working through the example, but am a bit leary of the Read() method's implementation.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth. Using https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/ you can turn your IAsyncEnumerable into a IEnumerable with the ToEnumerable() method.