# SqlBulkCopy throws "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, iasyncenumerable

I'm attempting to create a custom DataReader for an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` collection in order to load the records into a database table via `SqlBulkCopy`.  I'm following along the lines of the code example and solution outlined in this question - [How to use SqlBulkCopy to write an IAsyncEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994651/how-to-use-sqlbulkcopy-to-write-an-iasyncenumerable)

Here is the gist of my DataReader:

```
internal sealed class AsyncEnumerableDataReader<T> : IDataReader
    {
        private readonly IAsyncEnumerator<T> _asyncEnumerator;
        private readonly List<PropertyInfo> _properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        private bool _isClosed = false;

        public AsyncEnumerableDataReader(IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable)
        {
            _asyncEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                _properties.Add(propertyInfo);
            }
        }

 //.... Other method implementations here

public bool Read() => _asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync().Result;
}
```

My issue is that when I pass the datareader into the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader)` method, on the first call to `DataReader.Read()` it throws the following error:

> `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'`

Does anyone have any idea as to where I'm going wrong with my code?

Comment: Related: [System.InvalidOperationException when using GetAwaiter().GetResult() with ServiceBusReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913032/system-invalidoperationexception-when-using-getawaiter-getresult-with-servic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.Result` with a `ValueTask<T>` it does **not** block the current thread to wait for the result(`bool` in your case).

If a `ValueTask<T>` does not finish in time during it's first call it will return a `Task` that the CLR will use to continue work later to check on it.

The CLR can **not** check for the result later when you do not `await` the call.

Since you want to run this code synchronously(at least from what I can assume by using `.Result`) I have included a work around that should work for you *synchronously*.

Consider using `.AsTask().Result` instead of `.Result`. This will force the CLR to wait for the Task to finish before returning a result.

```cs
public bool Read() => _asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask().Result;
```